# What's the smallest natural number A such that $A\times B = C$ and none of the digits of C are zero? Does such a number always exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Lets say B is a natural number with n digits. Some of the digits of B are zero.
C is a natural number obtained by multiplying B with A. $$C=A\times B$$  Can you always find the smallest natural number A such that the number C doesn't have any digits which are zero? Is there any research done in this topic? Is this just trial and error?

Comment: Of course you'll need that the last digit of $B$ is not zero.

Comment: Well, if $10\,|\,B$ then no such $A$ exists.  If $\gcd(10,B)=1$ then $10^{\varphi(B)}-1$ is a string of $9's$ and it is divisible by $B$.  That probably won't be minimal, but at least it gives an upper bound to your search.  That leaves the cases in which $2$ or $5$ (but not both) divide $B$.

Comment: How do you know that $$10^(phi(B))-1$$ is a multiple of B? I think that information will be helpful to me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067752 shows existence.

Comment: @aschepler  Oh, thank you.  I was trying to find that.

Comment: @lulu It was in the automatically generated "Related" questions list. ;)

Comment: @RobertPuscasu  That's just [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)

Comment: @aschepler  Ah.  It's been pointed out to me before that I ought to sometimes look at that list.  Seems like good advice.